spring-data-redis lettuce caused off-heap memory ？why is off-heap memory？
in a production environment, direct use of redis pipeline policy of spring-data-redis , under certain conditions(it could be the Internet.), will cause off-heap memory to continue to rise, what is the reason for this? spring-data-redis version is 2.7.1.
I got some advice on github.I notice that the client disconnected buffer queue is an unbounded queue,this may be a problem here, but why caused out-of-heap memory?
Anyone help?thanks!
